# I removed /usr/lib/xorg by mistake, will copying it from the live cd be enough to repair?

Tags: xorg

I have a remote target (ARM board) and I was testing a script that recreates the folder structure of the target but with local debug libraries for easy remote debugging. The script doesn't re-download files I already have so I wanted to remove a folder to test this part (it didn't re-download, now I wanted to test that it downloads something)...

Instead of removing let's say `~/FolderInHome/usr/lib/xorg`, I did `cd ~/FolderInHome` and then `rm -rf /usr/lib/xorg`, it said `Permission denied`. I thought, maybe it has something to do with the target user being `root` and the files having the user rights set wrongly, so I did `sudo -rm /usr/lib/xorg` and done, it worked... Oops.

Currently, I tried to send the PC into sleep and it wakes up back all ok.

How could I recover my `xorg` folder? Is it enough to download it from a live cd?

Side note: I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Are you sure? There is, on any of my Ubuntu systems, no folder `/usr/bin/xorg`. There is a binary `/usr/bin/Xorg` which is provided by the package `xserver-xorg-core`. You could just reinstall that package. EDIT: or did you mean `/usr/lib/xorg`?

Comment: Yes, most probably it was /usr/lib/xorg. I remember searching to remove something from /usr/lib. I'll edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of the directory `/usr/lib/xorg` is a little harder to replace than the single binary file `/usr/bin/Xorg`. You can still do it by just reinstalling packages, but it's made up of many packages, some of which won't apply to you.

```
$ find /usr/lib/xorg -exec dpkg -S {} + | cut -d: -f1 | sed -e 's/, /\n/g' | sort -u
xserver-common
xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-input-evdev
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
xserver-xorg-input-wacom
xserver-xorg-video-ati
xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-mach64
xserver-xorg-video-mga
xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
xserver-xorg-video-qxl
xserver-xorg-video-r128
xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg-video-s3
xserver-xorg-video-savage
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion
xserver-xorg-video-sisusb
xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
xserver-xorg-video-trident
xserver-xorg-video-vesa
xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

While this is from a fairly stock machine, I'd check you have each of those installed already with the following:

```
apt-cache policy xserver-common xserver-common xserver-xorg-core \
xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-wacom \
xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev \
xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga \
xserver-xorg-video-neomagic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau \
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 \
xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage \
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx \
xserver-xorg-video-trident xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

And assuming you want all of those, reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-common xserver-xorg-core \
xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-wacom \
xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev \
xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga \
xserver-xorg-video-neomagic xserver-xorg-video-nouveau \
xserver-xorg-video-openchrome xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 \
xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage \
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx \
xserver-xorg-video-trident xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

---

If you did just mean `/usr/bin/Xorg`, you just need to:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-core
```

Comment: It installed additional packages: xserver-xorg-input-void and xserver-xorg-video-dummy. It restarted all ok but I don't have a mouse pointer nor does it take any input from it. I will look through the rest of the packages and install what is missing(seems like I had installed before that: xserver-xorg-input-mouse for example) - thanks.

Comment: I'll run this again on a 15.04 laptop and see if there are any other packages I've missed. As it is, the above is for 14.04 (because that's what I'm on).

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'd done some package manual cleaning on my desktop at some point. Updated the answer with what my laptop (which is 15.04) has.

Comment: That's about the packages I had to install. I also installed: xserver-xorg-input-mouse and xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse